# Обмен числами 2 и 3 питона

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Как использовать значения двух переменных, находящихся во втором питоне использовать в файле 3?

Переменный обновляются в цикле (Вы спросите почему нельзя запихнуть две проги в одну - ответ: у питона нет промежуточной версии, а либа для 3 питона не работает на 2, а для 2 не работает на 3).

Если знаете как подружить can-python и opencv - напишите!

Comment: opencv есть и для 3, и для 2 питона, python-can тоже . https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-can/ ,

Comment: В том и проблема, что опенсиви в третье питоне выдпёт гору ошибок и питон-кэн тоже, но наоборот

Comment: какой тип переменных?

Comment: @OLEERM вот лучше бы для начала попытаться разобраться с этими ошибками

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не остаётся другого варинта, попробуйте использовать какой-то вид Interprocess Communication, например сокеты, как описано здесь:
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socket.html#example

Вот мой вариант примера использования сокетов (написано в 4 часа ночи, так что не пеняйте сильно на код, пожалуйста ;) ).

test2.py:

```
import socket

f = open('log', 'w')
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind('/tmp/test_socket')
s.listen(0)
conn = s.accept()[0]
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break

    num = int(data)
    conn.sendall(str(num) + ':' + str(pow(num, 3)))
conn.close()
s.close()
```

test3.py:

```
import socket
import subprocess as sp
from time import sleep

with sp.Popen(['python', 'test2.py']) as proc:
    sleep(1)
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect('/tmp/test_socket')
        for i in range(10):
            s.sendall(bytes(str(i), 'ascii'))

            res = str(s.recv(1024), 'utf8')
            print('int: {}, pow3: {}'.format(*res.split(':')))
```

test2.py содержит код с использованием Python 2, а test3.py - с использованием третьей версии, соответственно. Из test3.py запускается test2.py, в котором открывается сокет и запускается сервер, который в цикле принимает по одному числу от клиента и возврвщает исходное число и его третью степень.

Вот результат вывода файла test3.py (который является клиентом):

```
int: 0, pow3: 0
int: 1, pow3: 1
int: 2, pow3: 8
int: 3, pow3: 27
int: 4, pow3: 64
и т.д.
```

Comment: Спасибо, сегодня попробую обязательно напишу результат.

Comment: код не заработал, но зато удалось поставить в 3 питон  opencv

Comment: Отлично, это всё же вариант получше. А что именно не заработало в коде? Конкретно этот запускали или свой вариант? Какие ошибки? В какой ОС запускали?

Comment: При каждом запуске надо было создавать новый сокет, потому что была ошибка в духе: этот сокет уже используется. Да запускал этот копи-пастом. Запускал под убунтой.

Comment: А, понятно. Да, эту ошибку я видел, но уже не исправлял: подумал, что работоспособность этой конструкции Вы увидите, а остальное допилите сами :)
Я тогда попозже поищу причину, по которой сокет не удаляется, или какое-то решение в виде удаления сокета как обычный файл (думаю, тоже будет работать) и добавлю в код "для истории".